# Search Term Wildcard

Tags: magento-1.9, search-terms

Is there a way to make it so search terms starting with "#10000" be sent to the "my account" page? We have a lot of people attempting to lookup their orders apparently through our search box. Instead of getting no results, might be cool to have them get the actual link to login with the redirect. Possible?

Comment: Not without customisation of the code - so that you overwrite the controller used to process the search request and intercept any order numbers. Magento doesn't provide a way to do this (that I'm aware of anyway!)

Answer (score 1):

You can, not exactly like you want but like this:
in app > design > frontend > [package] > [theme] > template > catalogsearch > result.phtml put

```
<?php if(strpos($this->getParam('q'),'#10000') !== false):?>
    You might be looking for an order. Click <a href='/customer/account'>here</a> to go to your account.
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: That worked but not as a wildcard. If I used 10000 it worked but I was hoping for any combination of numbers beginning with 10000. Is that possible?

Comment: It is a wildcard. strpos checks for the string #10000 in the search query. It will find #100001, #10000X, etc.

Comment: I put it right above the <h1> and I'm not seeing any message. Is there a better location? I know I' on the right file.

Comment: You are showing 0 interest to resolve this by yourself and instead asking everything here. You might be searching a string without the # in it. Also check your source code, it might be hidden by CSS.

Comment: I already checked the file, and then re-checked and I even said that.